# Codeigniter return array

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to return an array? This is my code (this is inside the model)

```
function getTeacherSchedule($id){
        $sections = $this->dbsections->query('SELECT * FROM sections;');
        foreach ($sections->result_array() as $section){
            $table = $section['NAME'];
            $tblsection = str_replace(array(' ', '-'),'_', $table);

            $schedule = ($this->dbsections->query('SELECT * FROM '.$tblsection.' WHERE TEACHER = '.$id));
            $result = $schedule->result_array();

        }

        return $result;
    }
```

And I want the result_array() of $schedule to be returned in a controller, but when i try to var_dump() it, it only returns a single record.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are storing a single record and overwriting it in every loop. Try -

```
function getTeacherSchedule($id){
    $sections = $this->dbsections->query('SELECT * FROM sections;');
    foreach ($sections->result_array() as $section){
        // rest of the code
        // .......

        $result[] = $schedule->result_array();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error "Undefined index" when I try to echo it

Comment: How you are trying to `echo` it? What `var_dump($result);` is printing?

Comment: It prints all the rows, but it seems like its a nested array

Comment: I have managed to print it properly using $sched[0]['SUBJ_NAME'], but I still get an error "Undefined offset: 0"